# How to label vertices of a simplicial complex in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels, labelling

I have the following code. My question is how one can label its vertices from 0 to 4? Thanks.

```
\newcommand\size{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[thick]  (18:\size) \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;

  \draw[thick] (18:\size) \foreach \a in {162,306,90,234} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;

  \foreach \a in {18,90,162,234,306} { \node[black, fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (\a:\size){}; }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome among us. Please complete your code to make it into a MWE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - I have not changed the values of `\a` for the label part, you can add `\b` additionally in the `foreach` statement for different labels

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand\size{1}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[thick]  (18:\size) \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;
        
        \draw[thick] (18:\size) \foreach \a in {162,306,90,234} { -- (\a:\size) } -- cycle;
        
        \foreach \a in {18,90,162,234,306} { \node[black, fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt,  label={[label distance=-3pt]\a:\footnotesize\a}] at (\a:\size){}; }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```